# Is there a way to have multiple opacities for nonselection glyph in bokeh?

Tags: python, bokeh

I have two linked scatter plots with points that have different opacities. The problem is that when some points are selected with the box-select tool, all the unselected points become the same opacity.

I would like for the unselected points to stay their original opacity. Points with different opacities can be linked, so I can't solve the problem by making an array of points for each opacity value.

Is there a way that I can achieve this within the plotting API?

Can I extend `nonselection_glyph` so its alpha attribute accepts an array of opacity values like the circle marker's alpha attribute does?

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import output_file, figure, gridplot, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Circle

N = 100
max = 100
x1 = np.random.random(size = N) * max
y1 = np.random.random(size = N) * max
a1 = np.random.choice(a = [0.2, 0.5, 1], size = N)
x2 = np.random.random(size = N) * max
y2 = np.random.random(size = N) * max
a2 = np.random.choice(a = [0.2, 0.5, 1], size = N)

output_file('scatter.html')
source = ColumnDataSource(data = dict(x1 = x1, y1 = y1, x2 = x2, y2 = y2,
                                      a1 = a1, a2 = a2))

left = figure(tools = 'box_select, tap', width = 400, height = 400,
              x_range = (0,100), y_range = (0,100))
right = figure(tools = 'box_select, tap', width = 400, height = 400,
               x_range = (0,100), y_range = (0,100))

points1 = left.circle('x1', 'y1', source = source, size = 10,
                      fill_color = 'blue', line_color = None, alpha = 'a1')
points2 = right.circle('x2', 'y2', source = source, size = 10,
                       fill_color = 'blue', line_color = None, alpha = 'a2')
points1.selection_glyph = Circle(fill_color = 'red', line_color = None)
points2.selection_glyph = Circle(fill_color = 'red', line_color = None)

p = gridplot([[left, right]])
show(p)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import output_file, figure, gridplot, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Circle

N = 100
max = 100
x1 = np.random.random(size = N) * max
y1 = np.random.random(size = N) * max
a1 = np.random.choice(a = [0.2, 0.5, 1], size = N)
x2 = np.random.random(size = N) * max
y2 = np.random.random(size = N) * max
a2 = np.random.choice(a = [0.2, 0.5, 1], size = N)

source = ColumnDataSource(data = dict(x1 = x1, y1 = y1, x2 = x2, y2 = y2,
                                      a1 = a1, a2 = a2, a1n = a1 * 0.5, a2n=a2*0.5))

left = figure(tools = 'box_select, tap', width = 400, height = 400,
              x_range = (0,100), y_range = (0,100))
right = figure(tools = 'box_select, tap', width = 400, height = 400,
               x_range = (0,100), y_range = (0,100))

points1 = left.circle('x1', 'y1', source = source, size = 10,
                      fill_color = 'blue', line_color = None, alpha = 'a1')
points2 = right.circle('x2', 'y2', source = source, size = 10,
                       fill_color = 'blue', line_color = None, alpha = 'a2')
points1.selection_glyph = Circle(fill_color = 'red', line_color = None)
points2.selection_glyph = Circle(fill_color = 'red', line_color = None)
points1.nonselection_glyph.fill_alpha = "a1n"
points2.nonselection_glyph.fill_alpha = "a2n"
p = gridplot([[left, right]])
show(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that `nonselection_glyph` *can* take an array of opacity values, but that array has to be in the `ColumnDataSource.`